# ROC curves - any way to get probabilities from tree models?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, roc

I am doing model selection with 10-odd models for a classification (binary) problem. I loop through each model, do a train-test-split, make predictions, and find the score, updating each score to a dictionary where the keys are the model.

However, many of these models (Decision Tree, Random Forest, AdaBoost, etc.) do not give probabilities as a float but rather the class as an int (1 or 0). This means that my AUC plots for these models have only three points.

My code:

```
fig = make_subplots(1,1)

ns_probs = [0 for i in range(len(y_test))]
ns_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, ns_probs)
ns_fpr, ns_tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_test, ns_probs)


for model in scores_kf_df.columns:
    fig.add_scatter(x=scores_kf_df.T.loc[model, 'fpr'],y=scores_kf_df.T.loc[model, 'tpr'], name=model)
    
fig.add_scatter(x=ns_fpr,y=ns_tpr, name='No Skill', line={'dash':'dot'})
    
    
fig.update_layout({'title':{'text':'ROC AUC Curve', 'x':0.5, 'font':{'size':28}},
                  'xaxis':{'title':'False Positive Rate'},
                  'yaxis':{'title':'True Positive Rate'}})
    
iplot(fig)
```

And my plot here:

[image]

Is there a way to get probabilities for these models, similar to the `predict_proba()` function in logistic regression?

Comment: yes, but you already know about it: `predict_proba`.  (A fully grown decision tree will still have many "perfect" 0/1 predictions, but the others will have more realistic probabilities.)  It's also not clear why you're using so many regressors in your classification task.

Comment: `DecisionTreeClassifier` contains a [`predict_proba` method](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.predict_proba), and similarly many of the other models used - https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ . Plus, SO does not work by simply throwing all our code here as-is - code here is supposed to be *minimal*, so also https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/

Comment: logistic regression has accessible probabilities.  Not all the classifiers give you easy access to the probabilities.

Comment: @desertnaur noted, I deleted some of the code. I included the full model train function because that’s needed to understand how many data points end up in the AUC curve. As predict_proba(), I need something works for ALL of these models, which predict_proba() does not. Wondering if there is a workaround to calculate this manually.

Comment: @benreiniger besides linear regression which are out of place? And I tried predict_proba() but it didn’t work for all models.

Comment: @goldenlion that’s where I’m at right now - weird because I feel like AUC curves with boosted models has got to be a pretty common combination for classification, no?

Comment: Still no solution to this, is there any workaround for all models selected?